# SQL Error [22007]: THE DATE, TIME, OR TIMESTAMP VALUE IS INVALID. SQLCODE=-180, SQLSTATE=22007, DRIVER=4.9.78

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2

I am trying to fetch value between a timestamp field from my code and current timestamp, but I am getting error.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT ST    
 WHERE
  ST.UPDT_TS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('01-01-2020 03:00:00') AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: That's an uncommon localized format. Use the ISO8601 format instead ('2020-01-01 03;00:00') or pass the date as a strongly typed date parameter

Answer (score 2):

Use `TIMESTAMP('YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mm:ss')` format instead of `TIMESTAMP('DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mm:ss')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT ST    
WHERE
    ST.UPDT_TS BETWEEN '2020-01-01 03:00:00' AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT ST    
WHERE
    ST.UPDT_TS BETWEEN '2020-01-01-03.00.00' AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP
```

valid DB2 timestamp values are listed in table 3 here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008474.html